# plotting is displayed upside down at MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am working on video surveillance on crowd density estimation. I am implementing a corner detection method for this project. However, I have a problem when my code is combined in GUI MATLAB, the display of plotting corner is upside down and it is not overlay on the original image. Here my code on plotting the image in GUI Matlab.

The problem is solved already and here is the correct code:

```
% Find row,col coords.
[r,c] = find(cim2);  

%After getting row and column coordinate, I plot them together in the original image which is
% overlay image and plotting

imshow(inFrame, 'Parent', handles.axes8);
hold on;
p1 = plot([c],[r],'r.');
set(p1, 'Parent', handles.axes8);
```

Thank you for @Lokesh for his suggestion.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "GUI Matlab"? Please show how you plot the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of your problem is very well given by floris.But here due to lack of  full your code we are not able to perform it on our system. you can aslo try for

```
axis ij
```

which is some what similar to above answer. you can also try the below code.

```
imshow(inFrame,'Parent',handles.axes8);
hold on;
p1 = plot([c],[r],'r.');
set(p1,'Parent',handles.axes8);
```

hope this works for you..let me know about the result..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is working properly. I added the correct code above. @Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

`imshow` inverts the Y axis. Conventionally, in image display the top left corner of the screen is `(0,0)` with `i` (the first coordinate) running down the screen, and `j` (the second coordinate) from left to right.

If you want the image axis to look like a conventional plot axis you can do

```
axis xy
```

This will "invert" your image, putting `0,0` in the bottom left.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @Floris, but still the plot of corner is upside down and the plot is not overlay on the original image. I also tried to use `set (gca, 'YDir','reverse');` but still no effect at all. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot? Does it work when you do `r=numRows +1-r;`? I realize it is a hack... It will help to diagnose.

Comment: It has been working properly and the correct code is attached above. Thank you. @Floris